# which is the correct form?

Tags: questions

I don't know which one is correct.

> - Let me know when you comes here.
> - Let me know when you will be here.

Please tell me which one is correct.

Comment: *Let me know when you comes here* is utterly incorrect. The latter one is still incorrect the way you typed! On this respected board, try not to use 'chat' language. *Let me know, when you will be here (or arrive)* is correct.

Answer (score 6):

"Let me know when you get here" is the most common way to express this idea. "Let me know when you are here" is also fine. "Let me know when you come here" is weird, since the process of coming from there to here takes some time, but "let me know when" is discrete.

By the way, at least in the US, abbreviating "you" as "u" is often seen as a little childish. I would never do it unless I was paying by the character (like on a telegram or something!)

Comment: Cool! I like your answer.................. Now how did you find "Cool!" in this context? I'd like to know if it's childish, etc?

Comment: +1 for " "Let me know when you come here" is weird, since the process of coming from there to here takes some time" because I could've done myself.

Comment: @learner *Cool* isn't childish.  It's now used by speakers of all ages.  It's not really appropriate in this instance, though.